# java.util.concurrent.Future.get() not returning

Tags: java, concurrency, multithreading, future, executorservice

I have the following Java code:

```
final Future future = exeService.submit(
    new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            myObject.doSomething();
        }
    }
);

future.get();
```

where `exeService` is an instance of

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService
```

The problem is that `myObject.doSomething()` never returns, and, hence, `future.get()` never returns.

However, if I replace the call to `submit` with a call to `execute` like this:

```
exeService.execute(
    new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            myObject.doSomething();
        }
    }
);
```

the call to `myObject.doSomething()` does return.  I don't know if it matters, but `doSomething()` is a `void` method.

Why is `doSomething()` finishing when using `execute` but not when using `submit`?

Also, I don't need to use `Future.get()`; that just seemed to be the most natural way of doing this.  (I also run into the same problem with `CountdownLatch`.)  The point is that I need to wait for `doSomething()` to finish before proceeding, and, for complicated reasons I won't go into here, I need to launch it on a separate thread.  If there is another way of doing this that works, that would be fine.

Comment: You're asking about the behaviour of `doSomething`, but tell us nothing about it. We can't help you here ...

Comment: Your question is pretty confusing. The first construct should just work. The confusion is in "returning". Don't you just mean "finishing" or "executing"? Your confusion seems to be based on the fact that `future.get()` actually *waits* for the runnable to be finished and thus will block the thread and prevent it from executing the remnant of the code after the `future.get()` line.

Comment: How are you creating 'exeService' ? Is it a ThreadPoolExecutor or something else ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As in [Executor.execute() Javadoc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html#execute%28java.lang.Runnable%29):

> Executes the given command at some
>   time in the future. The command may
>   execute in a new thread, in a pooled
>   thread, or in the calling thread, at
>   the discretion of the Executor
>   implementation.

So, the method `execute()` returns immediately leaving you with no option to query to status of submitted task.

On the other hand [ExecutorService.submit()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit%28java.lang.Runnable%29):

> Submits a Runnable task for execution
>   and returns a Future representing that
>   task. The Future's get method will
>   return null upon successful
>   completion.

The [Future.get()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get%28%29) will return *only* after successful competion, so *never* in your case.

This is further noted in [Future.get() documentation](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get%28%29):

> Waits if necessary for the computation
>   to complete, and then retrieves its
>   result.

Comment: *never*? So you insinuates that `myObject.doSomething();` is something like an infinite loop? Why does the other construct work then? Keep in mind that `void` is a perfectly valid return value.

Comment: I do not *insinuate* rather *conclude* :-). Author stated "The problem is that myObject.doSomething() never returns" so I assume this function is something like infinite loop (like server thread or sth).

Comment: Yes .. How would you then explain that it "does return" when using `execute()` instead of `submit()`?

Comment: I interpreted that it "continues the flow of execution" when he uses `execute()` and it doesn't when he uses `submit()` & `Future.get()`. I might have misinterpreted the question, but maybe I didn't.

Comment: It "returns" when using 'execute' since the thing is just fired off somewhere, and he never does wait for it to complete. When using submit() he does wait for it to complete, however it never does complete . If using a treadpoolExecutor there's 2 possible reasons: 1. the executor is tied up excuting something else. 2. The doSomething() never returns. e.g. it's an infinite loop.

Comment: @BalusC: I don't think the `doSomething` ever finishes in a case of `execute` as well.  It's just the calling thread never waits for it to finish, but `future.get` does.  The most likely problem is not an infinite loop, but a deadlock in `doSomething`.  I've seen my share of those.

Comment: +1 for reading into the question and breaking through the confusion of the OP

Answer (score 8):

I created an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org):

```
package com.stackoverflow.q2585971;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        Future<?> future = executor.submit(
            new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        System.out.println("Epic fail.");
                    }
                }
            }
        );

        System.out.println("Waiting for task to finish..");
        future.get();
        System.out.println("Task finished!");
        executor.shutdown();
    }

}
```

It works perfectly fine. It first prints

```
Waiting for task to finish..
```

then after one second you see

```
Task finished!
```

So, your problem lies somewhere else. I'll duplicate my comment on your question here:

> Your question is pretty confusing. The first construct should just work. The confusion is in "returning". Don't you just mean "finishing" or "executing"? Your confusion seems to be based on the fact that `future.get()`  actually waits for the runnable to be finished and thus will block the thread and prevent it from executing the remnant of the code after the `future.get()` line.

Answer (score 2):

Java futures are blocking!  `get(). This method blocks the current thread until a future instance completes its work, thus requiring the use of one thread more than the work that must be performed just to manage what happens when it is done`

Answer (score 0):

Check for a deadlock(s) in `doSomething`.

I would start with searching for [`wait`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29) calls.

If you `wait` for something, you need to signal the object you are waiting for from the other thread by calling [`notify`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify%28%29) or [`notifyAll`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notifyAll%28%29).